# How to tell the kernel to swapoff a file that is not visible with the filesystem any more?

Tags: linux, filesystems, kernel

I was told in response to my [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1478657/why-is-the-modification-date-of-my-swapfile-not-changing/1478661?noredirect=1#comment2232708_1478661) that the kernel uses files without the help of the filesystem - once a file is located the kernel just uses its location on the disk.

The example was an empty mountpoint (directory) where a file is located which the kernel uses as swap. After some time an external HDD gets mounted into this mountpoint. On this external HDD there is also a swapfile in the root directory. So, both files have the same path `/mountpoint/swapfile`.

My question is how to `swapoff /file` **the first file**. To be clear again: `swapoff /mountpoint/swapfile` will not work since this is the second file (after mount) which is not used by the kernel at that moment. At least I would suspect this.

I want to `swapoff` a file that is not visible in my filesystem.

(Yes, there are probably other solutions but I am curious about this.)

Comment: That post specifically applies to files being used **as swap**, not to files opened by the kernel in general. All regular file access still uses the filesystem, at most only bypassing the VFS layer (path lookups).

Comment: @grawity Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can identify the swap device/file you want to disable by its swap area UUID.

First list UUIDs of all swap areas:

```
$sudo swapon --show=SIZE,NAME,UUID -v
 SIZE NAME          UUID
1023M /dev/sda5     af72b528-c4fe-4dfe-8a1b-82e4d2d46d2a
1020K /tmp/testswap 32149ab7-bc18-4aef-872c-7b70ce144572
```

Then find the file you are after (testswap in my case) and disable it as follows:

```
$sudo swapoff UUID=32149ab7-bc18-4aef-872c-7b70ce144572
```

Verify that it is no longer active:

```
$ sudo swapon --show=SIZE,NAME,UUID -v
 SIZE NAME      UUID
1023M /dev/sda5 af72b528-c4fe-4dfe-8a1b-82e4d2d46d2a
```